# multiple outputs for "for word in ..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This code is support to scan messages and attempt to detect self-harm. If it detects this behavior then it sends a link to the suicidal prevention website as you can see in the screenshot. However, if it detects two different keywords which would trigger a response then it posts the desired message twice

```
suicide = ['wanna die', 'kill myself', 'kill me', ...]
for word in suicide:
    if (message.content.lower().count(word) > 0) and (message.author.id == 712885407993561169):
        await message.delete()
    elif (message.content.lower().count(word) > 0) and (message.author.id != 712885407993561169):    
        #message for the sucicodal prevention link goes here
```

[image]

Comment: You should loop through every word and set a 'Keyword detected' boolean and only carry out the action afterwards based on this value being true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop through every word and set a 'Keyword detected' boolean and only carry out the action afterwards based on this value being true.

```
suicide = ['wanna die', 'kill myself', 'kill me', ...]
delete_required = False
response_required = False

for word in suicide:
    if (message.content.lower().count(word) > 0) and (message.author.id == 712885407993561169):
        delete_required = True
    elif (message.content.lower().count(word) > 0) and (message.author.id != 712885407993561169):    
        keyword_detected = True

if delete_required:
    await message.delete()
elif response_required:
    embed = discord.Embed(description='\n**National Suicide Prevention Lifeline**\nHours: Available 24 hours\nLanguages: English, Spanish\n\n:paperclip: [Chat](https://suicidepreventionlifeline.org/chat/)\n:globe_with_meridians: [Official Website](https://suicidepreventionlifeline.org/)', color=0x00ff00)
    embed.set_author(name = 'Help is available\nSpeak with a counselor today', icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to stop the check as soon as the word is detected in the message string.

```
if (message.author.id != 712885407993561169) and any(word in message.content.lower() for word in suicide):
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
suicide = ['wanna die', 'kill myself', 'kill me', ...]
contained = False
for word in suicide:
    if (message.content.lower().count(word) > 0) and (message.author.id == 712885407993561169):
        await message.delete()
    elif (message.content.lower().count(word) > 0) and (message.author.id != 712885407993561169):    
        contained = True
if contained:
    #message for the sucicodal prevention link goes here
```

It will only send the message once as it is outside the loop so it will not get repeated if it contains 2 or more words.